# Phonegap Plugins Conflict with Camera

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using Phonegap to develop an App. I've got the Child Browser and Email Composer Plugins installed and they are working fine both in Simulator and on the phone but if I select an image from the phone library and then try and share that image, either plugins don't work.

Xcode gives me the error below:

WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  Source type must be UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

Any help on above would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any ideas, any one? It's PhoneGap (v1.4.1) that's throwing the error when I use the sourceType set to PHOTOLIBRARY or SAVEDPHOTOALBUM (sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM) .